# How to place XAMPP in Windows-Startup (not the User-Startup folder)

Tags: apache-http-server, boot, windows-server-2008

We have a **Windows 2008 Server** on which **XAMPP** is placed in the **Startup folder** of "Administrator” User. Which means that, in order to automatically start Apache, it requires the “Administrator” user to log-in at-least once.

The above Scenario is Problematic. Because, we don't know when this Server gets restarted.

To counteract this issue, I need to somehow **place XAMPP in Windows Startup** (not the User Startup).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

-Just Run "xampp-control.exe" as administrator
-and stop apache service action port.
-and tick this(in snapshot) check box it will ask for install as service just install it
-then go to service.msc where you will see
-new service name as apache2(or similar)
-just set it as automatic if you want it to run as startup.

(this method is for apache for mysql you will do same above steps)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

- Log in as administrator
- open XAMPP
- go to the control panel
- open the service settings
- enable the service settings and check all the services you want to be available (apache, mysql...)
- close XAMPP
- restart the server
- try

[image: XAMPP Control panel]

> Each server in XAMPP you can install also as Windows service. You can
>   also install it from the XAMPP Control Panel. In this case it is
>   necessary to run the scripts or the Control Panel with Administrator
>   privileges.
>
> Apache service uninstall: \xampp\apache\apache_uninstallservice.bat
>
> Apache service uninstall: \xampp\apache\apache_uninstallservice.bat
>
> MySQL service install: \xampp\mysql\mysql_installservice.bat
>
> MySQL service uninstall: \xampp\mysql\mysql_uninstallservice.bat
>
> FileZilla service (un)install: \xampp\filezilla_setup.bat
>
> Mercury: No service installation available

From [How can I install a server as a service](https://www.apachefriends.org/faq_windows.html)

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. I will let you know as I will apply it on the Server.

Comment: have you tried? did it worked?

Comment: Not yet tried..